# TypeError: object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, fastapi, python-unittest

I'm creating an application using `tortoise-orm` and `FastAPI`.

I wrote the following endpoint

```
@app.get("/status/", response_model=list[Status])
async def get_status() -> list[Status]:
    """
    Returns a list of Status objects representing the history/status of filtered messages.

    Returns:
        list[Status]: a list of Status objects representing the history of filtered messages.
    """
    history = await History.all()
    return list(map(Status.from_orm, history))
```

Nów here's my attempt to test it

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock, patch

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from source.craft.models import History
from source.main import app


class TestAPI(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client = TestClient(app)

    @patch("source.craft.models.History.all")
    def test_get_status(self, history_mock):
        object_mock = AsyncMock()
        object_mock.return_value = [
            History(id=1, text="Hello!", filter="lower", url=None, status="Done"),
        ]
        history_mock.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = object_mock

        response = self.client.get("/status")

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Unfortunately my test does not work. I get the following error

```
>       history = await History.all()
E       TypeError: object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression
```

What am I doing wrong? What is a correct way to test such functions?

Answer (score 4):

`patch` by default produces a MagicMock, so you need an AsyncMock there.

Here is simple working example you could use a reference.

```
from unittest import mock

class History:
    async def all(self):
        pass


async def foo():
    hist = History()
    await hist.all()


class TestHistory:

    @mock.patch('test_example.History.all', new=mock.AsyncMock())
    def test_history(self):
        foo()
```

If you need to manipulate the return value of your async mock, you could use the context manager approach for patching, and I would recommend to install `pytest-asyncio` to be able to use async/await in your tests.

```
class TestHistory:
    
    @pytest.mark.asyncio  # <--  pip install pytest-asyncio
    async def test_history(self):

        with mock.patch('test_example.History.all', new=mock.AsyncMock()) as all_history_mock:
            all_history_mock.return_value = "the list of all history"
            result = await foo()

        assert result == "the list of all history"
```